# Azure AD "Enterprise Application" - Support for SP relay state

Tags: azure-active-directory, saml

Can Azure AD "Enterprise Applications" return the service provider's (SP) relay state and if so, how do they?

I have had no problems with clients using ADFS or other Identity Providers.

Answer (score 0):

**Azure AD does support relay state. You will see the relay state as a parameter along with the SAMLResponse in the post to the ReplyURL.**

If the application is configured as IdP initiated SSO, you can specify the Relay State value in the app configuration on

> Azure AD > Enterprise Apps > [Select app] > Single sign-on > Show advanced URL settings > Relay State.